# How to change one point color on click in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to change the color of scatterplot points, one at a time. I have the code below which works, but I'm not sure how to change the color *back* when you click on a second point.

For example, I'd like it to work so if all the points are yellow by default and you click point A, point A alone turns black. Then when you click point B, point B turns black and point A turns back to yellow.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    var thisPoint = this.options;
                    thisPoint.color = 'black';
                    this.update(thisPoint, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a variable containing the last clicked point, for example (in an outer scope):

```
let previousPoint;
```

And then in your click event:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    // If we have a previous point, reset its color
                    if(previousPoint)
                        previousPoint.update({color: previousPoint.originalColor});
                    // Set this points color to black
                    this.update({color: 'black', originalColor: this.color});
                    // Make it our previous point
                    previousPoint = this;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/8vpLq6dy/7/) of it in use.

If you don't want to clutter the Point with the extra variable (originalColor) you can also put a `previousColor` in your outer scope along with the `previousPoint`.